# Encountered unknown tag 'snapshot' in DBT Snapshot

Tags: snapshot, dbt

I want to run a DBT Snapshot and am following a near-identical template to the one outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/snapshots#snapshot-configurations). However, I get the error when I run `dbt snpashot`

```
Compilation Error in model test_snapshot (.../project_folder/snapshots/test_snapshot.sql)    
Encountered unknown tag 'snapshot'.
        line 1
          {% snapshot test_snapshot %}
```

Below is the code I am attempting to compile.

```
{% snapshot test_snapshot %}
    {{
        config(
            strategy='check',
            unique_key='id',
            target_schema='snapshots',
            check_cols= 'all'
        )
    }}

select
        *
from {{ ref('modle_in_sample_folder') }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

The order of the snapshot folder and ref file is .../project_folder/snapshots/test_snapshot.sql and .../project_folder/intermediate/model_in_sample_folder.sql

Comment: I'd advise, as the docs say, to select data from source in the snapshot, and transform the data afterwards, rather than relying on a data model:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/snapshots#snapshot-source-data

Comment: What version of dbt are you running? The error is because dbt can't parse the `{% snapshot test_snapshot %}` line which would happen on a very old version of dbt (<0.14), when snapshots were called archives

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the location of my Snapshot folder. Once I moved it out of my models project folder, and up to one level in the folder hierarchy, I was able to run it successfully.

Comment: NOTE: It should be in the snapshots folder that is created when you init the project.